# Solving a recurrence relation with square root

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I ran into a bad recurrence relation. Anyone would calculate T(n) or add some hint?

$$T(n)  = \begin{cases}  n,\quad &\text{        if n=1 or n=0 }\\
\sqrt{1/2[T^2(n-1)+T^2(n-2)]+}n   ,\quad   &\text{   if n>1} \end{cases}$$

thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the sequence $a(n)=T(n)^2$. This sequence satisfies the recurrence relation
$a(0)=0, a(1)=1$ and 
$$
a(n) = T(n)^2=\frac{T^2(n-1)+T^2(n-2)}{2}+n = \frac{1}{2}a(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}a(n-2)+n,
$$
for $n\geq 2$. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: The homogeneous recurrence relation has a general solution of $b_n = c_1 \frac{1}{2^n}+c_2$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. This tells us that we should choose $a_n = n (\alpha n + \beta)$ as our guess for the particular solution.

Comment: Whoops. I meant that the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation is $b_n = c_1 \frac{1}{(-2)^n}+c_2$

Comment: the solution is not completed by @DPoole.

Comment: By my comment earlier, the general solution to this nonhomogeneous is of the form $a_n = c_1 (-.5)^n+c_n + n (\alpha n + \beta)$. You find the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from requiring that $a_n = .5 a_{n-1}+.5a_{n-2}+n$. Then using your initial conditions you determine $c_1$ and $c_2$. @Okh.Pij if you edit your post to give what you have tried, we could see where you are having issues.

Comment: What part of my previous comment are you having issues with?